# Cross-fade for inline text elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, text, jquery-effects, css

I am looking for a way to properly animate/crossfade inline anchor elements with jQuery. There are several solutions out there for block elements, but nothing so far for inline-elements.

My alternative text for each individual word comes from an attribute within the element:

```
<a data-r="nerd">word</a>​
```

But if I try to fadeout, replace the text and fade in, like here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a').click(function(index) {
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).text($(this).attr("data-r"));
    });
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

I am not getting the cross-fade effect that I would like, but a fadeout followed by a fadein, as you can see in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psychomachine/rYK3v/).

I'd be very grateful for any tips you might have.

Comment: You need _two_ elements to crossfade between. You can't crossfade between an element and _itself_, and you certainly cannot have the element contain _both_ words simultaneously while you crossfade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what i came up with:

```js
$('a').click(function(index) {
  var clone = $(this).clone();
  clone.css('position', 'absolute');
  clone.css('left', $(this).position().left);
  clone.css('top', $(this).position().top);
  $('body').append(clone);

  $(this).hide();
  $(this).text($(this).attr("data-r"));

  clone.fadeOut(500, function() {
    clone.remove();
  });
  $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
a { font-size: 60px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a data-r="nerd">word</a><br>
    <a data-r="dork">word</a>
</p>
```

You may have to adjust this to work with different `line-height`s, though.

Comment: I abstracted this out to its own function that accepted an element and copy as parameters, and the only change I had to make was replacing 'body' with the containing div selector. Thanks!